# Android studio Registro de usuarios, Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto haciendo registro de usuarios con firebase, i tambien un login por si tiene la cuenta creada, me gustaria poder saber si podrian ayudarme con alguna mejora para que quede perfecto, tenia pensado en el login añadiir un boton de por ejemplo, de que si no tiene cuenta que se vaya a register. Gracias.
descripción de la imagen aquí][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Phq.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Phq.png)
esto es el login

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Phq.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto es firebase

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Podrías para darle un toque de calidad, por ejemplo:

- Un botón para que restaure contraseña
- Añadir diferentes opciones de iniciar sesión (Google o Facebook)

Comment: Esto es más una opinión que una respuesta en si, por favor lee [answer]